# Python code to insert duplicate row based on number of comma in xls

Tags: python, excel

My Input in(xlsx) :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| R | 15,5 |
| A | 4 |
| C | 56,7,9 |

I am expecting output to be (xlsx):

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| R | 15 |
| R | 5 |
| A | 4 |
| C | 56 |
| C | 7 |
| C | 9 |

My code for this is:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

def duplicate_rows_with_comma(input_file, output_file):
    # Open the Excel file for reading
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(input_file)
    # Create a new Excel file for writing
    new_workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    # Iterate over each sheet in the workbook
    for sheet in workbook.sheets():
        # Create a new sheet in the new workbook
        new_sheet = new_workbook.add_sheet(sheet.name)
        # Iterate over each row in the sheet
        for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(row_index)
            # Check if column A contains a comma-separated value
            if ',' in str(row[5].value):
                # Split the comma-separated value into individual values
                values = str(row[5].value).split(',')
                # Create a copy of the row for each individual value
                for value_index, value in enumerate(values):
                    new_row = new_sheet.row(row_index + value_index)
                    # Copy values from the original row to the new row
                    for col_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                        new_row.write(col_index, cell.value)
                    # Update the value of column A in the new row
                    new_row.write(0, value.strip())
            else:
                # Copy the original row to the new sheet as it is
                for col_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                    new_sheet.write(row_index, col_index, cell.value)
    # Save the new workbook to a file
    new_workbook.save(output_file)
# Usage example
input_file = r'D:\sharing\Hope\6_1_2023\out.xlsx'
output_file = r'D:\sharing\Hope\6_1_2023\new_test.xls'
duplicate_rows_with_comma(input_file, output_file)
```

Any idea or lead will be helpful?

It is an simple excel manipulation by python where row are to be duplicated if there are multiple values in particular column B

Answer (score 1):

Please create a tuple from the input file and try below logic in your scenario

```
import xlsxwriter
 
# Workbook() takes one, non-optional, argument
# which is the filename that we want to create.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
 
# The workbook object is then used to add new
# worksheet via the add_worksheet() method.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 
# Use the worksheet object to write
# data via the write() method.
# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
scores = (
    ['Column A','Column B'],
    ['R','15,5'],
    ['A','4'],
    ['C', '56,7,9'],
)
# Start from the first cell. Rows and
# columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0
 
# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for col1, score in (scores):
    items = score.split(",")
    for item in items:
        print(col1,item)
        worksheet.write(row, col, col1)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        print(row, col)
        row += 1
 
# Finally, close the Excel file
# via the close() method.
workbook.close()
```

I've added print() statements for better understanding.